# Set border on the selected image of a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have a viewPager with infinite loop, but i want to set a border to highlight the current image.

In my main activity i've the adapter`PageAdapter` and the custom `ViewPager` (that is clickable).

I think that is easy, but i need help.

Something like this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: For this type of task, you can use `OnPageChangeListener` method's `onPageSelected`. onPageSelected returns the page number of viewpager which is currently visible to user.

Comment: to give border to imageview simply set the background and padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> > Place image view inside another layout set the background color of
> > parent layout.
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/border"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> ```
> > inside PagerAdapter instantiateItem method when you are setting bitmap
> > to imageView, also set backgroud color to layout.
> ```

```
final RelativeLayout border =  (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.border);
border.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```